# Automatic job resumption on flink cluster restart

Tags: apache-flink, restart

I am running jobs on a standalone flink cluster with a single Job Manager, running in a docker container. Whenever the cluster crashes and restarts, I have to submit the jobs manually again for them to start. Is there a way to make flink resume the jobs automatically once the cluster is running again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a job crashes because it throws an exception, the job manager will automatically restart it so long as (1) you have [checkpointing enabled](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/state/checkpointing.html) (it's disabled by default because it requires some configuration), and (2) you haven't set a [restart strategy](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/task_failure_recovery.html) that prevents restarts (the default restart strategy is fine). If a task manager in a standalone cluster completely fails, you'll need to start another one.

To configure job manager failover, see the [docs on high availability for standalone clusters](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/jobmanager_high_availability.html#standalone-cluster-high-availability).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But if there is a cluster failure, not just a job failure, such that we need to restart flink, in that case is it possible to make flink start the jobs that were going on when the cluster crashed.

Comment: Yes, if you run standby Job Managers, and setup zookeeper to store the metadata (about what jobs are running, checkpoints, etc) and to handle leader election, then you can recover from a cluster failure. See the page on high availability that I linked to above.